# How to catch The server sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am calling web service through my java SE application. when I run my application and processing long data it provide following error on netbeans console

> Exception in thread "Thread-2"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
>   sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error

I have use following code for caching errors

```
        try{
        ......
        } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error\nPlease Re-Process","Point Calculation",  0);
            Logger.getLogger(WeeklyPoint_processing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            progressPannel.dispose();
        }
```

but it doesn't catch  code 500: Internal Server Error.

What type of exception should I catch.

Comment: Based on the stack trace that you've posted, you need to catch `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException` exceptions, that will look something like this: `catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException | ClientTransportException e){....}`

Comment: It is unclear why you can not simply catch ClientTransportException.

Comment: ClientTransportException is throwed on client side because server is sending 500 as response code. Not make more sense to capture server error snd return a handled exception?